# How remove additional space in AppBar in Android Flutter App?

Tags: android, flutter

I have a problem with Appbar in Flutter. How remove additional space on screen? (black lines).

Screenshot

[image]

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainScreen({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Sample',
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        AppLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: const [
        Locale('en'),
        Locale('pl'),
      ],
      theme: theme,
      routerConfig: router,
    );
  }
}
```

```
final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: "/",
  routes: <RouteBase>[
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return SomePage(navController: _navController);
      },
      routes: <RouteBase>[
        GoRoute(
          path: 'page1',
          pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) => CupertinoPage(child: OtherPage1(navController: _navController)),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: 'page2',
          pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) => CupertinoPage(child: OtherPage2(navController: _navController)),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

```
class SomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final NavController navController;

  const SomePage({super.key, required this.navController});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          /* here is some code, not relevant for this problem */
        ],
        child: DefaultTabController(
          length: 3,
          child: BlocBuilder<CountersCubit, Counters>(
            builder: (blockContext, state) {
              FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(blockContext);
              return Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  leading: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () => { Navigate.back(navController) },
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
                  bottom: TabBar(
                    isScrollable: true,
                    indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                    indicatorColor: Colors.blue,
                    indicatorWeight: 3.0,
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(
                          text: processTextTabLabel(
                              label: AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                                  .header_view1,
                              counter: state.view1)),
                      Tab(
                          child: badges.Badge(
                        showBadge: false,
                        child: Text(processTextTabLabel(
                            label: AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                                .header_view2,
                            counter: state.view2)),
                      )),
                      Tab(
                          text: processTextTabLabel(
                              label: AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                                  .header_view3,
                              counter: state.view3)),
                    ],
                  ),
                  title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.header_title),
                ),

                body: TabBarView(
                  children: [
                    View1(navController: navController),
                    View2(navController: navController),
                    View3(navController: navController)
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

I tried:

1. Use SafeArea widget before scaffold container.
2. Set height Appbar.

I tried may ways witch i found on stack overflow and another sites. All not working in this case.
If I remove Appbar, view looks correct.

Comment: Hmm, the code you provided works fine. Can you provide the code where the `SomePage` class is put?

Comment: Utilize the Flutter inspector to determine which widget is associated with the white space then you can find the solution more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dhanusha Dilshan - I found resolve. Of course I tested yours solutions, but I had still a distance above appbar.
I add:

```
return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              primary: false, <- this line
              leading: IconButton(
```

And works.
App bar default has a distance for safe area, and change height appbar, we don't change this distance. Maybe I forgot write in my base post, this flutter app is module. Is add to native android App. So we don't need safe area.

Answer (score 0):

1.Solution-01,

Wrap your `AppBar` with `PreferredSize` and set `preferredSize` to zero.

```
appBar: PreferredSize(
  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0.0),
  child: AppBar(
   
  ),
),
```

2.Solution-02,

Use a custom `PreferredSizeWidget` for the AppBar.Create a custom `PreferredSizeWidget` and override the `preferredSize` to control the height of the AppBar.

```
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight); // Set your desired height here

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
    );
  }
}
```

then you can use this app bar as custom.

```
appBar: CustomAppBar(),
```

3.Solution-03,

Adjust the Scaffold's `extendBody` property.

Set `extendBody: true` within your Scaffold to make sure the body extends behind the AppBar, which might resolve the space issue.

```
return Scaffold(
  extendBody: true,
  appBar: AppBar(
  ),
  body: TabBarView(
    children: [
    ],
  ),
);
```

Try these solutions one by one to see if any of them resolves the additional space issue caused by the `AppBar`. Sometimes, the specific nesting of widgets or Flutter updates might affect how these solutions work.